# 音声ファイルをデータベースにアップロードできない。

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Laravelで音楽プレイヤーを作成しています。
プレイリストに追加したい曲をフォームからDB(MySQL)にアップロードしたいのですが、画面にThe file failed to upload.とエラーが出ます。（ファイルを選択ボタンの下）
フォーム入力 -> フォームリクエストによりバリデーション -> コントローラーでEloquantによりDB追加 という流れです。
なお、file_uploads、post_max_size 、max_file_uploads、upload_max_filesizeなどは全て問題ありませんでした。
(file_uploads = On、post_max_size = 32M、max_file_uploads = 20、upload_max_filesize =32M、音声ファイル（mp3）は大体８Mぐらいで１つずつアップロードします。)

どこを改善すれば良いのかご教示いただけると幸いです。

入力フォーム

```
<body>
  <div class="form">
    <div>
      <p class="add">楽曲追加</p>
    </div>
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="id">
    <div>
      <input type="text"  name="title" placeholder="楽曲" value="{{old('title')}}">
      @error('title')
      <p class="message">{{$message}}</p>
      @enderror
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text"  name="artist" placeholder="アーティスト" value="{{old('artist')}}">
      @error('artist')
      <p class="message">{{$message}}</p>
      @enderror
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="file"required>
    </div>
    <div>
      @error('file')
      <p class="message">{{$message}}</p>
      @enderror
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>アップロード</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

フォームリクエスト

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UploadRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'=>'required',
            'artist'=>'required',
            'file'=>'required|max:1600|mimes:mp3,wave,aif,aac,mp4',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required'=>'楽曲名を入力してください。',
            'artist.required'=>'アーティスト名を入力してください。',
            'file.required'=>'ファイル名を入力してください。',
            'file.max'=>'1.6MBを超えるファイルは添付できません。',
            'file.mimes'=>'ファイルの形式が正しくありません。',
        ];
    }
}
```

ルーティング

```
//楽曲追加画面表示
Route::get('/upload',[UploadController::class,'add']);

//楽曲追加
Route::post('/upload',[UploadController::class,'create']);
```

コントローラ

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UploadRequest;
use App\Models\Music;

class UploadController extends Controller
{ 
  public function add(){
      return view('upload');
  }
  public function create(UploadRequest $request){
      $form = $request->all();
      Music::create($form);
      return redirect('/upload');
  }
}
```

モデル

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Music extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];
    public static $rules = [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'artist' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required',
    ];
    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title . ' / ' . $this->artist;
    }
}
```

テーブル

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMusicTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('music', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('artist');
            $table->binary('file');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('music');
    }
}
```

自分で試したこと
php.info確認、formタグにenctype="multipart/form-data"追加

Answer (score 0, accepted):

貼って頂いたコードは、ファイルアップロードに関連する部分は特に問題ないように見えます。
ご推察の通りphp自体の設定やそれ以前のWebサーバやサーバ自体に原因がある気がしますね。

解決に至るか分からないのですが、次のことを試してみてください。

1. `(UploadRequest $request)` を一時的に `(Request $request)` に変更する。

   - スクリプト冒頭に `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` が無かった場合はそれも必要
   - この変更でアップロード失敗時もコントローラーまで処理が来るようになる（今は来てないはず）
2. アップロード処理の冒頭で `dd($request->file('file')->getError());` とする

   - 一時的にバリデーションを外した状態でアップロード失敗時のエラーメッセージをブラウザに表示
3. 普段失敗している時と同じ方法でサイドアップロードしてみる。

   - 上で仕込んだ `dd()` からのエラーメッセージが表示されるかもしれません。

もしこれでエラーを表示することが出来た場合、そこに原因が書いてある可能性があります。

ここから先はLaravelではなくphpになりますが、phpのファイルアップロード処理に影響を与える設定は冒頭の4つの他にもあります。

PHP: POST メソッドによるアップロード - Manual
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/features.file-upload.post-method.php
注意: 関係する設定に関する注記

> php.iniの file_uploads, upload_max_filesize, upload_tmp_dir, post_max_size, > max_input_time ディレクティブも参照ください。

今回の原因になっているかは分からないんですが `upload_tmp_dir` 辺りは環境依存のエラーを引き起こしやすいですね。アップロードしたファイルをphpが一時的に保存しておくディレクトリの問題（多くの場合ディスク容量や書き込み権限）が原因だった、ということが経験上は多いです。今回の原因になっているかは解りません。